# get build status through github api

Tags: github, github-api

The [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) provides a lot of functionality, but is there a way to retrieve the build status for a commit? The GitHub UI provides information from the CI system we have configured, but I can't see this information exposed through the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can access the status for a particular ref](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#list-statuses-for-a-specific-ref)

`GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:ref/statuses`

For the value of `:ref`, you can use a SHA, a branch name, or a tag name.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't provide status directly, but offers you to **[*create* a status](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/)**

That means the CI can have a final build step which *publishes* the status to GitHub repo that way.

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/statuses/:sha
```

For example:

```
{
  "state": "success",
  "target_url": "https://example.com/build/status",
  "description": "The build succeeded!",
  "context": "continuous-integration/jenkins"
}
```

(and that, for a given SHA1)

---

See for instance "[Github Commit Status API with Bamboo from Atlassian](https://gist.github.com/pcreux/4976429)", where:

- `${bamboo.buildResultsUrl}` is the GitHub commit SHA1:
- `<xxx>` is a placeholder value, which can be replaced by a value, or a variable `${var}` as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70410456/6309).

> Add those to your plan as Script.

- `complete.sh`:

  ```
    # specs and cukes results are stored in JUnit format under test-reports
    if (grep 'failures="[^0]"' test-reports/* || \
      grep 'errors="[^0]"' test-reports/*); then
      curl -H "Authorization: token <MY_TOKEN>" --request POST \
        --data '{"state": "failure", "description": "Failed!", \
        "target_url": "${bamboo.buildResultsUrl}"}' \
        https://api.github.com/repos/<USER>/<REPO>/statuses/${bamboo.repository.revision.number} > /dev/null
    else
      curl -H "Authorization: token <MY_TOKEN>" --request POST \
        --data '{"state": "success", "description": "Success!", \
        "target_url": "${bamboo.buildResultsUrl}"}' \
        https://api.github.com/repos/<USER>/<REPO>/statuses \
        /${bamboo.repository.revision.number} > /dev/null
    fi
  ```
- `pending.sh`:

  ```
    curl -H "Authorization: token <MY_TOKEN>" --request POST \
      --data '{"state": "pending", "description": "Build is running", \
      "target_url": "${bamboo.buildResultsUrl}"}' \
      https://api.github.com/repos/<USER>/<REPO>/statuses/${bamboo.repository.revision.number} > /dev/null
  ```

Comment: I was unaware what the `${bamboo.repository.revision.number}` was initially (it's the GitHub commit SHA), and was a bit confused by the `MY_TOKEN`, `USER` and `REPO` variables not being started with a `$` as I am used to in bash. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410456/set-github-commit-build-status-from-bash-using-ssh) contains a less convoluted bash example of this answer. Also, the target url should start with `https://`, so `stackoverflow.com` as target url would not suffice. (However the `> dev/null` obfuscates such error messages).

Comment: @a.t. Thank you. I have edited this 6 years old answer to take into account your comment and its very good points.