# Set GitHub commit build status in Bash using SSH?

Tags: bash, github, commit, github-api

While trying to set the build status of a commit through ssh, I was experiencing some difficulties. I first set the build status successfully, using a [GitHub personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29444071/7437143), I created the following curl command:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER="red"
REPO="code"
COMMIT_SHA="6ec8d6ef221c3e317fa20b1f541770b8f46f065c"
MY_TOKEN="somelongpersonaltoken"
curl -H "Authorization: token $MY_TOKEN" --request POST --data '{"state": "failure", "description": "Failed!", "target_url": "https://www.stackoverflow.com"}' https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/statuses/$COMMIT_SHA
```

Which sets the build status similar to the red cross below:
[image]

Next, I retrieved the GitHub commit status, using:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/commits/$COMMIT_SHA/statuses
```

Which outputs:

```
[{"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/... ,"state":"failure","description":"Failed!","target_url":"https://www.stackoverflow.com","context":"default","created_at":"2021-12-19T10:10:20Z","updated_at":"2021-12-19T10:10:20Z"...,"site_admin":false}}]
```

Which is as expected.

Then for the second part, I tried to omit using a GitHub personal access token, and use my ssh credentials to set the commit build status. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15047403/7437143) seems to suggest that that is currently not possible. Hence, I would like to ask:

*How can I set a GitHub commit build status using ssh credentials in Bash?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stand by my [2013 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15047403/7437143) and confirm, in late 2021, that using SSH for GitHub API URL seems not supported.

Even the latest [GitHub CLI `gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) command only proposes HTTPS calls, not SSH.

> Makes an authenticated HTTP request to the GitHub API and prints the response.
>
> The endpoint argument should either be a path of a GitHub API v3 endpoint, or "graphql" to access the GitHub API v4.